# RaphaelJS: arrow's end and start have different color than the path itself

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, raphael

```
var paper = new Raphael('paper');
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    paper.path([
        'M', i * 20 + 30, 10,
        'L', i * 20 + 30, 300
    ]).attr({
        'stroke-width': 5,
        'stroke': ((i%2==0) ? 'red' : 'blue' ),
        'arrow-end': 'block-midium-midium',
        'arrow-start': 'oval-narrow-short'       
    });
}
```

The actual lines of the arrow have the correct colors, but the arrow end/start have the same color

**Check here:** http://jsfiddle.net/MGtUQ/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [known bug](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/471). It's not on master repository yet, but you can fork [v2.1.2 version from GitHub](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/v2.1.2). It should be fixed there already.

**Edit**:
Fix was implemented in this [commit](https://github.com/vkaravir/raphael/commit/e3b7545f7cde6d23188bc15c98fabd9f099de057). For anyone who will use it I'm highly recommend to update after fix will be ready in release version to avoid not supported code.

Line `5963` in [raphael.js](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js) file.

Comment: it's not yet committed to either master or v2.1.2. but found the fix here https://github.com/vkaravir/raphael/commit/e3b7545f7cde6d23188bc15c98fabd9f099de057 . just needed to replace that line in the uncompressed raphael.js.. post this link or the exact steps for accepted answer. the exact line is `5963` for `raphael.js` file thank you

Answer (score 3):

for those who has raphael-min.js
search for: `B="raphael-marker-"+r+w+x+y;`
and substitute it with `B="raphael-marker-"+r+w+x+y+"-obj"+d.id;`

Comment: Worked like a charm for me in version 2.1.2